# Does spring mvc have response.write to output to the browser directly?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc with freetemplate.

In asp.net, you can write straight to the browser using Response.Write("hello, world");

Can you do this in spring mvc?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can either:

- get the `HttpServletResponse` and print to its `Writer` or `OutputStream` (depending on whether you want to send textual or binary data)

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/something")
  public void helloWorld(HttpServletResponse response)  {
    response.getWriter().println("Hello World")
  }
  ```
- Use [`@ResponseBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody):

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/something")
  @ResponseBody
  public String helloWorld()  {
    return "Hello World";
  }
  ```

Thus your `Hello World` text will be written to the response stream.

Comment: so @responsebody then ignores the view resolver? I am using freemarker

Comment: Can a similar method be used to send a file directly to the output stream? Thank you.

Comment: @kmehta you will have to get the `OutputStream`. I'm not sure about the `@ResponseBody` approach.

Comment: Nice. Turned out to be real simple using Spring MVCs FileCopyUtils.copy()..which takes a filestream and an output stream. Thanks for the reply +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an annotated controller (or non-annotated for that matter I believe...), you can use the method argument `HttpServletResponse` in your controller to get the output stream and then write to the screen - see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29

For more information about the parameters you can use in your controllers/handlers, see
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html (section 13.11.4)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it is possible in some contexts.  For example, if you have the `HttpServletResponse` object available to you (as you do in a `Controller`, or if you write your own `View`), then you can call `getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` and write to that.

But you need to be careful to make sure that what you are doing doesn't interfere with your use of FreeMarker templates.  And I'm not sure if you could manage it from within a FreeMarker template.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send something to OutputStream, even if you are using Freemaker, just use @ResponseBody

example:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "report1", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
    @ResponseBody
    public void getReport1(OutputStream out) {
```