# Return file from Spring @Controller having OutputStream

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc

I want to return a file from a Spring controller. I already have API that can give me any implementation of OutputStream and then I need to send it to a user.

So the flow is something like that:

getting outputstream **->** service passes this outputstream to controller **->** controller has to send it to a user

I think I need inputstream to do it and I have also found Apache Commons api feature that looks like this:

```
IOUtils.copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
```

but the problem is, it converts it to the other side -> not from **os** to **is**, but from **is** to **os**.

## Edit

to be clear, because I see the answers are not hitting right thing:
I use Dropbox api and recieve file in OutputStream and I want this output stream to be sent to user while entering some URL

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(); //can be any instance of OutputStream
DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/fileName.mp3", null, outputStream);
```

Thats why i was talking about converting **outputstream** to **inputstream**, but have no idea how to do it. Furthermore, I suppose that there is better way to solve this (maybe return byte array somehow from outputstream)

I was trying to pass servlet outputstream [response.getOutputstream()] through parameter to the method that downloads file from dropbox, but it didnt work, at all

## Edit 2

The "flow" of my app is something like this:  @Joeblade

1. User enters url: **/download/{file_name}**
2. Spring Controller captures the url and calls the **@Service layer to download** the file and pass it to that controller:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "download/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public void getFileByName(@PathVariable("name") final String name, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
       response.setContentType("audio/mpeg3");
       response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
       service.callSomeMethodAndRecieveDownloadedFileInSomeForm(name); // <- and this file(InputStream/OutputStream/byte[] array/File object/MultipartFile I dont really know..) has to be sent to the user
   }
   ```
3. Now the @Service calls *Dropbox API* and downloads the file by specified **file_name**, and puts it all to the OutputStream, and then passes it (in some form.. maybe OutputStream, byte[] array or any other object - I dont know which is better to use) to the controller:

   ```
   public SomeObjectThatContainsFileForExamplePipedInputStream callSomeMethodAndRecieveDownloadedFileInSomeForm(final String name) throws IOException {
       //here any instance of OutputStream - it needs to be passed to client.getFile lower (for now it is PipedOutputStream)
       PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream(); // for now
       PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream);


       //some dropbox client object
       DbxClient client = new DbxClient();
       try {
           //important part - Dropbox API downloads the file from Dropbox servers to the outputstream object passed as the third parameter
           client.getFile("/" + name, null, outputStream);
       } catch (DbxException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           outputStream.close();
       }
       return inputStream;
   }
   ```
4. **Controler recieves the file** (I dont know, at all, in which form as I said upper) and passes it then **to the user**

So the thing is to recieve `OutputStream` with the downloaded file by calling `dropboxClient.getFile()` method and then this `OutputStream` that contains the downloaded file, has to be sent to the user, how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream`. Example:

```
// A ByteArrayOutputStream holds the content in memory
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// Do stuff with your OutputStream

// To convert it to a byte[] - simply use
final byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

// To convert bytes to an InputStream, use a ByteArrayInputStream
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

You can do the same with other *stream pairs*. E.g. the file streams:

```
// Create a FileOutputStream
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt");

// Write contents to file

// Always close the stream, preferably in a try-with-resources block
fos.close();

// The, convert the file contents to an input stream
final InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("filename.txt");
```

And, when using Spring MVC you can definitely return a `byte[]` that contains your file. Just make sure that you annotate your response with `@ResponseBody`. Something like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/myurl/{filename:.*}")
public byte[] serveFile(@PathVariable("file"} String file) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/" + filename, null, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: yeah, worked perfectly :) But my question is whether it is good practice to create multiple streams? and where should I close (if any) any of these created streams? I want performance to be as good as possible

Comment: Well, the problem with the Byte-streams is that you keep everything in-memory. If the file is big it also means that you keep a lot of bytes in-memory. The best approach would probably be to pass the `response.getOutputStream()` directly. Why did that not work out for you?

Comment: I dont actually know, when I return void from controller and save the file to response.getOutputStream() then nothing happens when I enter the URL, but when I return byte[] from controller and add some headers to the response everything is right; And also question: how to check if file is not empty? (when pass filename, that doesnt exist in Dropbox, then I get not some empty response with appropriate for example 404 code, but empty file and 200 OK)

Answer (score 45):

Get the OutputStream from the HttpServletResponse and write the file to it (in this example using IOUtils from Apache Commons)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void download(HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(PATH_TO_FILE)); //load the file
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
    ...
}
```

Make sure you use a try/catch to close the streams in case of an exception.

Comment: @John Smith, I am trying to download audio file (.wav) your solution works fine on my development machine (Windows OS) but when I deploy on Ubuntu Server, It only returns 200 bytes that results in corrupt file which is not playable... any idea whats wrong with running solution on ubuntu??

Comment: Here is a reference with this same sort of solution (flushing file stream to response): https://twilblog.github.io/java/spring/rest/file/stream/2015/08/14/return-a-file-stream-from-spring-rest.html

Comment: (Sorry if this is pedantically mincing words, but I'm curious of the difference). Does this sort of solution stream the response itself?  Or is the response not streamed, but rather first created <i>from</i> a stream (before returning it in a non-stream response)?

Answer (score 29):

The most preferable solution is to use [InputStreamResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html) with `ResponseEntity`. All you need is set `Content-Length` manually:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity download() throws IOException {
    String filePath = "PATH_HERE";
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentLength(Files.size(Paths.get(filePath)));
    return new ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: aren't we going to close the stream ? I mean, how is stream being closed.

Comment: Stream is wrapped into HttpServletResponse, so receiver should close it. I think Servlet container must handle this under the hood.

Comment: `HttpHeaders` are not required. You may write `return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(Files.size(Paths.get(filePath)).body(inputStreamResource)`

Answer (score 5):

I recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725508/1197030)

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/photo2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public byte[] testphoto() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/images/no_image.jpg");
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

answered by michal.kreuzman

I was going to write something similar myself but ofcourse it's already been answered.

If you want to just pass the stream instead of first getting everything in memory you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20540647/1197030)
I haven't tested this (not at work) but it looks legit :)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "report1", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
@ResponseBody
public void getReport1(OutputStream out) {
    InputStream in; // retrieve this from wherever you are receiving your stream
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.flush(); // out.close? 
}
```

The thing is, this is pretty much the same as [IOUtils.copy](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) / IOUtils.copyLarge does. line: 2128
Which you say copies the wrong direction.

However first make sure you understand what you ask. If you want to read from an outputstream(object for writing) and write to an input stream (object to read from) then I think what you really want is to write to an object that also supplies a read option.

for that you could use a PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream. These are connected together so that bytes written to the outputstream are available to be read from the corresponding input stream.

so in the location where you are receiving the bytes I assume you are writing bytes to an outputstream.
there do this:

```
// set up the input/output stream so that bytes written to writeToHere are available to be read from readFromhere
PipedInputStream readFromHere = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream writeToHere = new PipedOutputStream(readFromHere);

// write to the outputstream as you like
writeToHere.write(...)

// or pass it as an outputstream to an external method
someMather(writeToHere);

// when you're done close this end.
writeToHere.close();


// then whenever you like, read from the inputstream
IOUtils.copy(readFromHere, out, new byte[1024]);
```

If you use IOUtils.copy it will continue to read until the outputstream is closed. so make sure that it is already closed before starting (if you run write/read on the same thread) or use another thread to write to the output buffer and close it at the end.

If this is still not what you're looking for then you'll have to refine your question.

Comment: @azalut if this doesn't help then i'm not sure I understand the question :D

Comment: apperciate your update :) i have tried your answer and it is good but still not perfect; when I enter the URL that sends me the file, then I recieve it, but it is empty and has no extension. After I download the file from dropbox, I want that file to be sent to the user somehow; I will update my post for a moment and maybe then you could help me even more :)

Comment: i found out the problem; when I type in url: name.extension, only the name is saved to @PathVariable and the extension is not, so I had to use some reg-exp's to match that and now works fine :) although I still need to check somewhere, if my file is not empty

Answer (score 3):

The most memory-efficient solution in your case would be to pass the response `OutputStream` right to the Dropbox API:

```
@GetMapping(value = "download/{name}")
public void getFileByName(@PathVariable("name") final String name, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, DbxException {
    response.setContentType("audio/mpeg3");
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\"");
    response.setContentLength(filesize); // if you know size of the file in advance

    new DbxClient().getFile("/" + name, null, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

Data read by the API will be sent directly to the user. No additional byte buffer of any type is required.

---

As for `PipedInputStream`/`PipedOutputStream`, they are intended for the blocking communication between 2 threads. `PipedOutputStream` blocks writing thread after 1024 bytes (by default) until some other thread start reading from the end of the pipe (`PipedInputStream`).

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind when writing to the response outputstream is that it is a very good idea to call `flush()` on whatever writer that you've wrapped it with periodically. The reason for this is that a broken connection (for example caused by a user canceling a download) may not end up throwing an exception for a long time, if ever. This can effectively be a resource leak on your container.