# How to return ModelandView when metod returning ResponseEntiry<Resource> throws an error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, httpresponse

I have the following method

```
@GetMapping("/{fileName}")
public Object downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
    // Load file from database
    errors.clear();

    DBFile dbFile;

    try {
        dbFile = dBFileStorageService.getFileByName(fileName);

    } catch (MyFileNotFoundException ex) {
        logger.info("File has not been found.");
        errors.add(ex.getMessage());

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
    logger.info("Delivering file");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(dbFile.getFileType()))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + dbFile.getFileName() + "\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(dbFile.getData()));

}
```

Instead of returning Object I would like to return `ResponseEntity<Resource>` if it possible to return the file or `ModelAndView("redirect:/")` otherwise.

I tried:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Location", "/member/uploadImage");    
return new ResponseEntity<>(headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

But instead of redirection I got message that the file I am trying to download is corrupted. 
Summing up I would like to change method signature to:

```
public ResponseEntiry<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName)
```

Comment: So... since it's `Object`, why can't you already do exactly that?

Comment: I am not sure if returning an object is the best/proper way to do this.

Comment: A perhaps more idiomatic *Java* way would be to let that exception escape and handle it in an `@ExceptionHandler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your first question on returning the file through ResponseEntity is already answered here  :
 [Return file from Spring @Controller having OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741283/return-file-from-spring-controller-having-outputstream)

Agreeing wwith @chrylis, as he suggested the best approch for you to take in case of an exception is to throw the exception and handle it in sprind `@ControllerAdvice` class using `@ExceptionHandler` method annotation.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  // 409 or according to your need any code
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ModelAndView unhandledExceptionHandler(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("handling exception here!!!");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("errorView");
        mv.addObject("ERROR", "ERROR OCCURRED REDIRECTED "+ex.getMessage());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Official [Doc](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).